# asp.net : how to automatically identify user / returning user

Tags: asp.net

i see a lot of web site that.. remember when i return without using registration. 
I think they save cookies or something... 
So i'm asking you: in asp.net / vb.net how can i save the id of a user ? 
What are the command to do this ? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

Here is some VB.NET to read/write cookies.  Pretty straight forward:

```
Sub SubmitBtnWrite_Click(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs)
    Response.Cookies("TestCookie1").Expires = "5/1/2010"
    Response.Cookies("TestCookie1").Value = _
        "The cookie stuff."
    Response.Cookies("TestCookie2").Expires = "5/1/2010"
    Response.Cookies("TestCookie2").Value = _
        "More cookie stuff." End Sub

Sub SubmitBtnRead_Click(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs)
Dim I as integer
For I = 0 to Request.Cookies.Count - 1
    lblMessage1.Text = lblMessage1.Text  _
        & Request.Cookies.Item(I).Name & ": " _
        & Request.Cookies.Item(I).Value & "<BR>"
Next End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [use cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx).

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but you'll need to do actual research and write actual code.

Comment: +1 this Link is very good and explains basic usage.

In addition to that, the membership provider is a good hint for user account .

Answer (score 0):

SLaks is correct - use cookies.  The [Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx) control has this functionality built in.